# How to parse a model to an ajax post call

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-boot

Im trying to parse a model that i loaded with spring using `model.addAttribute("myModel",mymodelvariable);` to an ajax call (the model is beeing used in a form).
 Is there a way to call my Spring controller and send that model now with data to my controller back? and if not, how to parse the data of the form as an object to my controller using ajax?

Here´s what i tryied using @Html:

```
$('#sampleForm').submit(

    function(event) {
        var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/hellohello',
            type : "POST",
            data : data,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
            },
            success : function(response) {
               $('#reloading').html(response);
            },
            error : function(err) {
                alert("not working")
                console.log("not working. ERROR: "+JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

controller:

```
 @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
 @ResponseBody
 @RequestMapping(value = "/hellohello",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView step1(@ModelAttribute Mymodelvariable mymodelvariable){

      //do stuff and return model
    }
```

Comment: The structure of `data` in the ajax call must match the structure defined for `Mymodelvariable` class, also, I think you don't need to use the `@ModelAttribute` anymore since the `POST` will automatically map the request body to `mymodelvariable`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This may Help You

```
$('#sampleForm').submit(

function(event) {

    var data={
        "name":$('#name').val(),
        "age":$('#age').val(),
        "xyz":$('#xyz'+str).val(),
        "xyz":$('#xyz'+str).val(),
        "xyz":$('#xyz'+str).val(),
        "xyz":$('#xyz'+str).val(),
        "xyz":$('#xyz'+str).val(),

       }
  $.ajax({
        url : "././hellohello",
        type : "POST",
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        },
        success : function(response) {
           $('#reloading').html(response);
        },
        error : function(err) {
            alert("not working")
            console.log("not working. ERROR: "+JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Controller class:

```
  @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
  @RequestMapping(value = "/hellohello",method = RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView step1(@RequestBody Modelclass mymodelvariable)throws 
      Exception{

  //do stuff and return model
}
```